# Why is vertex snapping with auto merge enabled not merging vertices?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, snapping

I am watching [**this**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jg-GUvYRHcU) tutorial on youtube:

[image]

At the moment, the tutor is merging the hand's vertexes to the arm's vertexes; the problem is that when I try to merge them like that, they don't really get really well merged and end up having empty space between them. This is what I am saying:

[image].

How can I fix this? Thank you already!

Comment: Try doing it without mesh display enabled on the subserf modifier (triangle icon). I'm not sure why it's working in the video, though it does look like he was using 2.62 (I'll test it in 2.62 in a second..)

Comment: @gandalf3 Dude!! Thank you so much! You don't know how happy I am; I have been searching for a solution for hours already. Awesome! No need to test it if you want to.

Comment: This does work in 2.62. I'll report this (and another bug I found while testing this). In the meantime, a faster way to merge two loops (assuming the vertex counts are the same): **1.** select the loops you want to merge **2.** Bridge them (W > Bridge) **3.** Enter edge select mode (Ctrl Tab > Edge) and Ctrl Alt Right click on one of the newly created edges **4.** Press Alt M > Collapse. If the vertices are lined up enough, you could also try W > Remove doubles with the two loops selected, then press F6 and increase the merge distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The video is of 2.62, where this seems to work. In current versions of blender you need to disable *Applied edit cage* on your modifiers for snapping + auto-merge to work reliably:

[image]

I've reported this [here](https://developer.blender.org/T40680).

---

However, in this case there are some potentially faster ways to merge these loops.

### Loops with equal vertex count, but not necessarily even vertex placement:

1. Select both loops and press <kbd>W</kbd>*> Bridge Edge loops* (<kbd>E</kbd>)
2. Switch to edge select mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>*>* Edge) and select the newly created edge ring by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> over one of the new edges.
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>*> Collapse* to collapse the selected edges.

[image]

### Loops with lined up vertices, but not necessarily the same vertex count:

1. Press <kbd>W</kbd>*> Remove doubles* and up the merge distance in the redo panel (<kbd>F6</kbd>). This will result in triangles with uneven vertex counts, and it could produce tris even with equal vertex counts.

[image]