# How do I fix the pivot point of my vertex

Tags: modeling, transforms, vertices

The pivot point of every vertex in the mesh of my object is out of position for some reason how do I put it back to where the geometry of my vertex actually is. I tried origin to cursor but it will say you could not do apply this in edit mode.

[image]

As illustrated in the picture above the pivot point is far from where the vertex is located.

Comment: Yes the 3d Manupalor's origin is what I am talking about. here is the copy of my .blend file. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4ur9ysuxvkea3y/Mananaggal%20Raider%20Bone%20%28Rigged%2C%20Texture%2C%20Hair%2C%20Weights%2C%20Animation%29%20V2.blend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the armature modifier is not taken into account (this is [intended behavior](https://developer.blender.org/T40680#10)), so the pivot point is at the non modified location of the selection.

This becomes obvious when toggling *Modified edit cage* (the triangle icon on the modifier):

[image]

To make things more manageable, try disabling the modifier in edit mode:

[image]

Also see [Why is vertex snapping with auto merge enabled not merging vertices?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12310/599)

Answer (score 0):

Switch out of edit mode back to object mode and try the "Origin to 3D Cursor" operation again.  It should work.

Comment: yes it works but that is not what I wanted to do. I want to fix each vertex so that the pivot of every vertex is in its center. Not the pivot of the whole 3d object itself.

Comment: You can assign  every vertex of a mesh to be a pivot point, but only one at a time. You do this by setting the pivot point to "active element", and selecting the vertices as you want to change the pivot point. Just as you cannot have more than one active element at a time, you cannot have more than one pivot point at a time.

Comment: well the problem is when I snap using the magnetic too from vertex to vertex. It does not snap correctly, it snaps to the point where the pivot seems to be located. This is happening in all vertices

Comment: @user4956 Do you have any modifiers?

Comment: Sounds to me like you have scaled, rotated, or translated the vertices, without applying the translation, scale or rotation. To do this, go to object mode, and press SHIFT-Akey, or from the operation search function, type "apply".

Comment: @brasshat The scale and rotations shouldn't affect snapping. Also `Shift A` is Add, did you mean `Ctrl A`?

Comment: Yes, gandalf3, I did mean "CTRL-Akey". And while I wouldn't expect rotation to affect snapping, i'm not as sure as you are that translation would not. Also, this would not be the first time I found Blender behaving in a way I didn't expect. Of course, most of the time the fault lies with my expectations, but still.......

Comment: @brasshat I did what you said and it still does not solve the problem. Here is the copy of my .blend file [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4ur9ysuxvkea3y/Mananaggal%20Raider%20Bone%20%28Rigged%2C%20Texture%2C%20Hair%2C%20Weights%2C%20Animation%29%20V2.blend)

Comment: Post a ~.blend file.

Comment: @brasshat I posted the link to the file above