# Why is snap cursor to active not working?

Tags: snapping

It works in certain vertices but sometimes I get this.

[image]

Comment: Are there any modifiers on mesh ? Do they have "Adjust cage to result" button turned on in their [interface](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html?highlight=modifiers#interface) ?

Comment: Ah, of course. It's working fine, it's just showing the position without the subsurf modifier. Thank you.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13486/how-do-i-fix-the-pivot-point-of-my-vertex